# The Bent Washer Problem -- divide a shape into 2 pieces of the same volume.

Tags: general-topology, recreational-mathematics, solid-geometry

Fans of the [Ham sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem) know that any set of points can be divided by a plane into two equal halves.

Consider instead a 3-D shape that must be divided into 2 equal pieces by a single cut.  A sufficiently bent spring washer or keyring cannot be divided into 2 pieces by a plane.  But it's possible to make a simpler cut that works -- a partial plane cut.

Is that the simplest shape that cannot be split into 2 pieces by a plane?

Is there a simple shape that cannot be split into 2 equal pieces by a simple cut?

Comment: The ham sandwich theorem just promises that you can cut the set into two sets of equal volume.  It does not guarantee that the sets will be contiguous.  Even in 2D a spiral shaped region will be cut into more than two pieces.

Answer (score -1):

The Ham Sandwich Theorem says that given three measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be cut into two equal (with respect to measure) pieces by a single plane. In particular, we can choose two of our sets to be empty. So any measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be cut in half by a plane.

EDIT: I originally misunderstood. You're interested in when the cut pieces are connected.